# ASP.NET Core read HTML email and display in webapp

Tags: html, email, parsing, web-applications, blazor

I am working on a custom email webapp for my company. I have browsed the web and can't find an exact answer. Maybe I don't know what to "google" for exactly. I have never done anything email related.

In our database we are saving emails as a string. It contains everything.
`<DOCTYPE><head><body><style>` etc. How would I go about displaying this in my webapp.

I tried just pasting the HTML in a `<div>` inside one of my components but the styles would not load properly.

How would I go about reading/parsing the raw HTML in the string to then display it in my webapp. Is there a nuget package anyone recommends.

I am using Blazor on .net core 5.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have found, putting an email HTML body into an existing web page will almost result in CSS pollution as the HTML may have styles (or may use styles from the web page).

My solution to this was to load and display the email HTML inside an `<iframe>` tag as this isolates the email from the page very effectively. The URL for the IFRAME is separate view on the server, which just returns the raw email HTML (remember to add security to this if needed in your app).

There are probably better ways to do this in CSS now without having to resort to IFRAME.